# ShowDialog call on OpenFileDialog crashing WPF application because of SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a WPF application (x64, .Net 4 ) using Visual Studio 2015. As a part of Application Home Page, I have a button which will open File Browser.

The Button Click event is as follows...

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal.ToString();
openFileDialog.Title = "Select Profile Configuration Files";
openFileDialog.Filter = "Profile Config Files (*.cfg)|*.cfg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     try
     {
         _LoadConfigProfile(openFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message, "Error Opening Prfile", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
     }
}
```

But, everytime I am clicking the button, File Browser is opening, but then within a second, the application is getting crashed. 
Using Breakpoints, I have figured out the crash is occuring in the line `openFileDialog.ShowDialog()`.

The error, shown in VS2015 is as follows

[image: Error Window]

Call Stack is as follows
[image: Call Stack]

As a part of the application, I am using SQLite to handle some data. I have opened a DataBase Connection at the beginning of Application.

Has anyone faced such problem before ? How can I solve this ?

Comment if you want any more information regarding the application and the error.

Comment: it's not a good practice to keep connections open for long periods, you should connect to db only when you need it

Comment: You check the version of SQLite. SQlite comes with 64 and 32 bit. Make sure you use 64 bit version of SQlite.

Comment: I am using 64bit version, but still not successful.

Comment: As a data point, and I know it doesn't help, I am writing a WPF application in .net 4.5 using VS 2005 and using SQLite as well, and when I open the file selector it also crashes, but not even into the debugger. This code is nowhere near any SQLite handling code.

Comment: @Woody, I faced the same situation, couldn't solve this ultimately.

Answer (score 3):

The file selector is in the common control DLL that is probably not loaded in a WPF application until you call create an OpenFileDialog object. Check the output log to see that it isn't loading a different (additional) sqlite.dll at this point.

As mentioned in the comments, I had this problem and I had avoided using file selectors before, but with a new requirement I had to add one and on doing so the application crashed again just after the file selector dialog shows.

If you look at the output log, it shows the line number in the sqlite source which is a thrown exception in sqlite3_config if it is called while the library is already in use.
Looking further back in the output log shows that just before this exception occurred, commoncontrols.dll and an additional sqlite.dll were loaded from from C:\Program Files(x86)\Dell Backup And Recovery\ - i.e., a different sqlite.dll than was already in use, and certainly not a location for a library, but presumably earlier in the path. I uninstalled Dell Backup and Recovery and the error no longer occurs.

Comment: As far as I remember, I figured some way out (which I can't remember) and finished the project few months ago. But, I must say, what you are saying, actually does make sense. I am also using a Dell laptop with "Dell backup and Recovery" installed in it. So, may be, this was the problem, which I failed to figure out. Thanks for sharing this.